# Customize axis in flutter charts and remove dashes

Tags: flutter, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to space a bit more the following bars from the legend and remove the "tick" line and cannot figure out how to do that.

[image]

I'm using charts_flutter: ^0.8.1
The code I have right now is as follows

```
            Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              child: charts.BarChart(
                series,
                animate: true,
                vertical: false,
                defaultRenderer: charts.BarRendererConfig(
                  cornerStrategy: const charts.ConstCornerStrategy(0),
                ),
                primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                  renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
                ),
                domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                  showAxisLine: false,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
  showAxisLine: false,
  renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
    tickLengthPx: 0,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I already had it solved, look the comment above. Thanks anyway, by looking at the code I'd say this would work well too

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by setting a renderSpec overriding the lineStyle

```
                  renderSpec: new charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(

                    lineStyle: new charts.LineStyleSpec(
                        color: charts.MaterialPalette.transparent),
                  ),
```